# Apache Drill Filter Pushdown Case

Tags: apache-drill, apache-calcite

I have a requirement to query the federated data resides in different
vendors DB's in different servers, let's take an example,

```
SQL: SELECT t1.NAME,t2.AMOUNT FROM server1.mysql.USERS AS t1 INNER JOIN
server2.oracle.PURCHASES AS t2 ON t1.ID =t2.USER_ID WHERE t1.NAME ='ABC' AND
t2.TYPE ='Sales';
```

When I am executing this query t2.TYPE ='Sales' filter was not pushed down to the table level so here,

1. How the Drill will overcome the entire table scan, it can cause a performance impact.
2. How to push t2.TYPE ='Sales' filter to table level.

Thanks and Regards

Ajay Babu Maguluri.

Answer (score 0):

I have created [DRILL-7340](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-7340) for this issue and described the root cause of the problem there. The complete fix requires changes in both projects: Drill and Calcite.

The good news is that PR with the fix in Calcite was created and after it is merged and Drill rebased onto the new Calcite version, this issue will be fixed.